# send id of all selected option from one page to another without $_post[]

Tags: php, post

```
<?php
        $i=1;
        $ph='php';
        echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\">";
        $query=mysql_query("select question,id from ques where category=\"$ph\" order by rand() limit 5",$con);
        if(!$query)
        {
            echo mysql_error().'query failed';
        }
        $ans=1;
        while($value1=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "Q-$i"."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo $value1['question']."<br />";
            $i++;
            $qno=$value1['id'];
            $query1=mysql_query("select id,option1,option2,option3,option4 from ques where id=$qno");
            if(!$query1)
            {
                echo mysql_error().'query failed';
            }

            while($value2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
            {
                $opt=$value2['option1'];
                $opt1=$value2['option2'];
                $opt2=$value2['option3'];
                $opt3=$value2['option4'];
                $id=$value2['id'];

                echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt\" name=\"$ans\">";
                echo "<span class=\"margin\">$opt</h1>";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt1\" name=\"$ans\">";
                echo "<span class=\"margin1\">$opt1</h2>";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt2\" name=\"$ans\">";
                echo "<span class=\"margin2\">$opt2</h3>";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt3\" name=\"$ans\">";
                echo "<span class=\"margin3\">$opt3</h4>"."<br /><br />";
                $ans++;             
            }

        }
        echo"<center>"."<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">"."</center>";
        echo "</form>";
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
            $correct=$_POST[1];
            $_SESSION['value']=$correct;
            /*$correct1=$_SESSION['value'];
            echo $correct1;*/
            $correct2=$_POST[2];
            $_SESSION['value1']=$correct2;
            /*$correct3=$_SESSION['value1'];
            echo $correct3;*/
            $correct4=$_POST[3];
            $_SESSION['value2']=$correct4;
            /*$correct5=$_SESSION['value2'];
            echo $correct5;*/
            $correct6=$_POST[4];
            $_SESSION['value3']=$correct6;
            /*$correct7=$_SESSION['value3'];
            echo $correct7;*/
            $correct8=$_POST[5];
            $_SESSION['value4']=$correct8;



            /*$correct9=$_SESSION['value4'];
            echo $correct9;
            $j=1;
            while($j<=$i-1)
            {
                $correct=$_POST[$j];
                $_SESSION['$j']=$correct;
                $j++;
                $correct1=$_SESSION['$j'];
                echo $correct1."<br />";
            }*/

            header("location:quizresult.php");
        }
            ?>
```

I don't know how to send id of selected option to the next page.I want to retrieve the id of selected option in the next page because from this i can get the correct answer of the selected question or any other solution of this and i get the only one id on the next page

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways how to carry over values to the next page. I used the following successfully before:

**1. Use a $_SESSION variable**

Save the option values in session variables and retrieve them on the next page.

**2. Use hidden form fields**

You can save them as part of the form but in a hidden form field and retrieve it on the next page via $_POST.

An excellent tutorial (4 pages) for HTML forms and its various inputs is here:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-tutorial-p1.phtml

**3. Use a http query**

You can append a http query to your link to the next page, containing the values, i.e.

```
http://www.example.com/next-page?option1=value1&option2=value2
```

On the next page you can use `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY)` to extract the values. I would recommend that only if you do not submit a form though. I use this option if I create action buttons that are linking to the next (or the same) page and a single action has to be performed before the page is displayed.
Some generic info about query strings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: i am save the option in the session and it will sucessful retrieve on the next page but the only one id is retrieve on the next page

Answer (score 0):

```
$qno= $_SESSION['id'] = $value1['id'];
```

Id is being saved in $_SESSION['id'] and will be available on the ext page also.

retrieve it like this

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```